# Which redis funtionality is similar to SDIFF for SortedSets

Tags: redis, set, ranking, sortedset, sdiff

```
Observations : 

1. SDIFF only works with Set. It doesn't support SortedSets.
```

Query :

1. In absence of SDIFF, what can be used for Sorted set for similar use-case as SDIFF

Answer (score 1):

1. Short answer is no. A Sorted Set has members and scores. Nothing more. However, you can easily store the metadata in another key in Redis using the `entityId` as part of the key. So, for example, if your `entityId` was `foo` you could store that metadata under a key name something like `Entity:MetaData:foo`. This key could be a simple String, or any data structure in Redis.
2. Use [ZDIFF](https://redis.io/commands/zdiff). It's like SDIFF, but for Sorted Sets.

Comment: Do we need to make another call for getting top 10 entities? ZDIFF doesn't provide that functionality. Also i don't need sortedSet functionality for trackedEntities. Do i still need to make it a SortedSet for ZDIFF.

Comment: Yes, you would need to make another call (or just do it in your code if you don't have too much data). ZDIFFSTORE works just like ZDIFF but stores the result in a new Sorted Set, which could be useful for this. And ZDIFF will allow you to pass in Sets or Sorted Sets. So trackedEntities can be a Set.

Comment: Also, if you use ZDIFFSTORE, you'll probably want to delete the Sorted Set when you are done. Although you could leave it in memory for a bit to cache the results. Depends on the specifics of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Unfortunately it is extremely costly operation for large input